# Django Apache Redirect Problem

Tags: django, apache, redirect, mod-wsgi

I'm configuring my Django project to run on Apache using mod_wsgi. I am attempting to run Django below the directory 'cflow' on apache, but am running into problem with redirects.

My apache conf looks something like this:

```
...
WSGIScriptAlias /cflow "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\wsgi\django.wsgi"
<Directory "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\wsgi">
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
<Directory "C:\Projects\myproject\src">
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

The problem I'm running into is that if the user is not logged in, a request for /cflow/somepage.html will be reidrected to /accounts/login?next=/cflow/somepage.html. This new address is not below the django root (cflow), so apache responds with a 404 Not Found.

My question is how can I have the Django redirects mapped to be below the applications root directory on apache? I.e. how can I make the /accounts/... page be instead /cflow/accounts/...?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 15):

Things to try:

1. Change current domain to "yourdomain.tld/cflow" in the ["sites" framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/sites/). It's easy to do using django admin or dumpdata/loaddata manage.py commands.
2. Looks like your site is using [login_required](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator) decorator. In that particular case you can add to [settings.py](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#login-url):

   LOGIN_URL = '/cflow/accounts/login/'

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping for a solution that was transparent to the Django app. I'd like to be able to test the site on one address/server and deploy on another without any additional configuration.

I'll look into the sites framework, though. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: I thought it would be more straightforward, too, but this is definitely a correct answer. I was having the same problem and finally found this answer. Thanks alex!