# Moving Django site to another server- WSGIScriptAlias causing problems

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi, django-wsgi

I'm in the process of moving a django site over to a new server. On the old server, the django site was accessed like mysite.com/ , but now, we would like to access it via mysite.com/mysite, and let mysite.com handle something else. I have made the following changes to apache like so:

```
    WSGIDaemonProcess mysite processes=2 threads=15 display-name=%{GROUP}
    WSGIProcessGroup mysite
    WSGIScriptAlias /mysite /srv/www/django.wsgi
    #WSGIScriptAlias /mysite /srv/www/django.wsgi  #previous config         

    <Directory /srv/www/mysite/mysite >
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>

    Alias /site_media "/srv/www/mysite/site_media/"
    Alias /admin_media "/srv/www/mysite/admin_media/"
```

This seems to work fine- pointing the browser at mysite.com/unity/admin allows me to access the admin page correctly, and view the respective apps correct. However, anything that uses a custom template seems to be half-baked. For instance, there's an entry in a template below like so:

```
 {% ifcodable cl.model %}<li><a href="/report/{{ app_label }}/{{ cl.opts.verbose_name }}" class="link">Coding Report</a></li>{% endifcodable %}
```

This will redirect the page to

```
http://mysite.com/report/texas/texas
```

As opposed to

```
http://mysite.com/mysite/report/texas/texas
```

I'm not sure if the template is set up incorrectly or if it has something to do with the new alias. My urls.py looks like so:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    .....
    (r'^report/([a-zA-Z]+?)/([a-zA-Z]+?)/(overall|\d+)/{0,1}$', 'mysite.k.views.performance'),
    (r'^report/(.+?)/(.+?)/{0,1}$', 'mysite.k.views.report'),
    .....
```

My django.wsgi file looks like so:

```
import os,sys
sys.path.append('/srv/www/mysite')
sys.path.append('/srv/www/mysite/mysite')
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) + '/..')
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'settings'
import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

I don't know what the proper thing would be to do to correct the problem. I'm fairly new to django, so if there is a wicked simple solution I apologize. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your url begins with `/report` in the href attribute. Beginning with a `/` means that it should be relative to the root of your domain. I believe what you need to change is how the Django sites framework is configured, and it looks like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1466708/run-django-with-url-prefix-subdirectory-app-works-but-urls-broken) has the answer.

Also, you should probably use the [url tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#url) in your templates instead of hardcoding the urls in your anchor tags.

Comment: +1 for the `url` tag. If you'd always used that, the URLs would automatically be correct.

Comment: I saw that question/answer listed before although the answer doesn't really help- don't quite understand that. I'm checking out the url tag- that looks useful. I didn't create the templates, I just inherited them :(

Comment: Ah, well the hacky solution would be to change that link to `/mysite/report/...`