# How to set default url in settings.py for "www.example.com/path"

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-settings

I am trying to deploy my django on a server, but this server has an extra tag for the url like this. `http://john.example.com/mywebsite` instead of `http://john.example.com`

so whenever I want to redirect from the homepage to other pages, I got error messages because the redirected pages are missing the extra tag `/mywebsite`

for example
I want to direct to `http://john.example.com/mywebsite/apple` but when I choose on link on the template it direct me to `http://john.example.com/apple`

so I just wonder if there is a way to fix this by setting default home directory to `http://john.example.com/mywebsite` instead of `http://john.example.com/` so I don't have to fix all my code

Thanks you

Comment: Is there a reason you have the `mywebsite` tag in the url??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Running Django site with a URL prefix](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19642932/running-django-site-with-a-url-prefix)

Comment: Yes It isn't my server. It belongs to my Prof. that he gave us one for each team

Answer (score 1):

In your **settings.py**, add `FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME = 'path',` where `'path'` is the directory where the project resides.

For example, if your site exists at `http://john.example.com/mywebsite`, **settings.py** would contain `FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME = '/mywebsite'`.

Comment: thanks I'm trying it now. will update the result asap

Comment: unfortunately, it didn't solve my problem. I'm trying to fix it now.